# Source Model Error when accessing Catalog->Manage categories on backend

Tags: magento-1.9

We have this error when trying to access Catalog -> Manage categories:

There has been an error processing your request

Source model `productsfilter/attribute_source_productsfilter` not found for attribute `productsfilter_dis_attributes`

Trace:

```
#0 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "p...')
#1 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(203): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/bonjour-promo_com/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}
```

I've trying to remove this Product Filter Extension but unfortunately, this doesn't resolve the error.

Can anyone support me to solve this issues?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove some attribute created by this extension, which are using Source model `productsfilter/attribute_source_productsfilter`.

You can search `productsfilter` string in the `eav_attribute` table and remove those attribute from Database.